# Quickly find object in Swift Array

Tags: swift

I need to find an object in an array quickly. In my code I am using this method:

```
 var marker_Detials: MarkerDetails?

 _ = self.markersArray.contains { (details: MarkerDetails) -> Bool in
          if let location = location {
            if location.id == details.marker?.id {
              marker_Detials = details
              return true
            }
          }
          else if let marker = marker {
            if marker == details.marker?.maker {
              marker_Detials = details
              return true
            }
          }
          return false
        }
        return marker_Detials
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arrays have the [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) method

```
let marker_Detials = markersArray.first { details in
    return (location != nil && location!.id == details.marker?.id)
        || (marker != nil && marker == details.marker?.maker)
}
```

Comment: The condition in your code is too simplified that it does not generate exactly the same result as shown in the OP. For example, if `location` is nil, it may return the first `details` where its `marker` is nil, which would not be expected.

Comment: @OOPer I updated my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: As far as I can see, the updated condition is equivalent to the original.

Comment: Thanks nice small code and working perfectly !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

***is this correct way***

NO. Your implementation depends strongly on the current implementation of `contains`, which does not guarantee it applies the closure from the first element to the last. Even though it is very unlikely that the current implementation would completely be changed, having side-effect in boolean closure (so-called predicate) may easily cause unexpected results and not recommended.

Swift Standard Library has a method to find first element in Array, why don't you use it?

```
public func first(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element?
```

With using `first(where:)`, your code would be:

```
    let marker_Detials = self.markersArray.first { (details: MarkerDetails) -> Bool in
        if let location = location {
            if location.id == details.marker?.id {
                return true
            }
        } else if let marker = marker {
            if marker == details.marker?.maker {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    return marker_Detials
```